# Remove second item from JSON array string

Tags: c#, json

Suppose I have the following JSON

```
[{"ID": 1}, {"ID": 2}]
```

Which is the best way of removing the second item without know the JSON object type?

This is what I should like to have:

```
[{"ID": 1}]
```

I tried to use string manipulation but I am looking for a better solution

Comment: What have you already tried so far?

Comment: Have you considered deserializing to a list/array, removing the element and then serializing to JSON again?

Comment: do you want to remove specific one (with id =2), or leave only one item in the array (with id = 1)?

Comment: I tried to use string manipulation but I was looking for a better solution

Comment: @Dino "better" is highly depended  on context, but you can deserialize to Newtonsoft's [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) and iterate through it.

Comment: If you can provide information on the .NET framework you are using (4.5, Core 2.0, Core 3.0 etc) then there might be other options other than using the Newtonsoft library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string json = @"[{""ID"": 1}, {""ID"": 2}, {""ID"": 3}]"; 

var definition = new[] { new { ID = "" } };

var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, definition).ToList();

if(list.Count >= 1)
    list.RemoveAt(1);

json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list); // Result : [{"ID":"1"},{"ID":"3"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you should be converting the `string` to a `JSONArray` using a library called `Newtonsoft`. That'll make it much more easier to operate on the string and make your code much more maintainable and readable.

That being said if you had to do it using `String Manipulation` I'd recommend you use `regex` to match elements in a `{}` for JSON objects and then use `string.Replace()`.

Below is a piece of code:

```
string input = "[{\"ID\": 1}, {\"ID\": 2}, {\"ID\": 3}]";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\{(.*?)\}");
var matches = regex.Matches(input);

if (matches.Count < 2)
    throw new System.Exception("The content size must be at least two.");

// in case the collection only has 2 elements then there is no "," at the end.
string trailing = matches.Count > 2 ? "," : string.Empty;

var toRemove = matches.ElementAt(1).ToString() + trailing; 

input = input.Replace(toRemove, string.Empty);

System.Console.WriteLine(input); // prints out [{"ID": 1}, {"ID": 3}]
System.Console.ReadLine();
```